# Lattice theory in mathematics and physics

Tags: crystals, lattice-model, graph-theory

I have undertaken a project examining lattice model and trying to construct algorithm that could work on all lattice (in physical sense, or crystal structure). I notice there is a branch in mathematics called lattice theory which deals with ordering.

I am wondering whether the lattice theory in mathematics could actually help me in construct such "general algorithm" which can deal with any kinds physical lattice. If so, I will delve into this area. Please help me, thanks.

If you know a more specific mathematical area that deals with general physical lattice ( I have some names in my mind like, mathematical crystallography, lattice graph theory). Please hint me so that I could move forward. Thank you.

Comment: Cross-posted from http://math.stackexchange.com/q/548336/11127 Dear user40780. In general, it is frown upon to cross-post simultaneously, because it may waste potential answerer's time. As a minimum OP should mention the cross-post (on both sites!). The preferred procedure is to not cross-post, and if the post hasn't received an acceptable answer after, say, a couple of days, then OP could flag for migration.

Comment: Post discussed in chat here http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29309419#29309419 and below.